# Combine multiple rows with partial NA values into single row after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that has many NAN values. The data frame is shown below.

[image]

This is one example.
Here i want row 5 and 6 to be merged wherever there is NAN. Also row 12 and 13 can also be merged as one. I want to merge where ever possible and keep all the distinct combinations.
The column Main_ID represents each user, hence i need to group by on that.
I am not able to do this and need some help on the same.

Comment: Please make a minimal, reproducible example and tell us exactly what you want to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, and if as it appears in your example all of the columns are either numerical or datetime, you should be able to just do this:

```
pd.groupby('Main_ID').max()
```